# How do I add times in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, date-arithmetic

How do I add times in C#?  For example:

```
Time = "14:20 pm" +  "00:30 pm"
```

Comment: "00:30 pm" isn't a valid time. I'm confused as you have a PM but the time is obviously in 24hr format. A starting point for you is DateTime.ParseExact http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx but without clarification on the time format I can't help more than that.

Comment: What should be the semantics of adding two points in time? Do you mean to add a time span (e.g. 30 minutes) to a point in time?

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you want to add 30 minutes to a given DateTime, you can use [AddMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx).

```
TestTime.AddMinutes(30);
```

Another way of doing it:

```
DateTime TestTime = DateTime.Parse("22 Jun 2009 14:20:00");
// Add 30 minutes
TestTime = TestTime + TimeSpan.Parse("00:30:00");
```

Answer (score 4):

You would want to convert both times into a TimeSpan objects.

This will give you explicit access to the Hours/Minutes values of each time and you can add them together.

See [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: Nope, just the second one. DateTime + TimeSpan = DateTime

Comment: Yeah your right Leppie, I was just being more thorough so they could access the hours/minutes property for both times :)

Answer (score 4):

```
 TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan(14, 20,0);
 TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(0,30,0);
 Console.Out.WriteLine(t1 + t2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (although 0:30pm doesn't make sense):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new StringTime("14:20 pm").Add(new StringTime("0:30 pm")));
        Console.WriteLine(new StringTime("15:00 pm").Add(new StringTime("0:30 pm")));
        Console.WriteLine(new StringTime("5:00am").Add(new StringTime("12:00pm")));
    }
}

class StringTime
{
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public bool IsAfternoon { get; set; }

    public StringTime(string timeString)
    {
        IsAfternoon = timeString.Contains("pm");
        timeString = timeString.Replace("pm", "").Replace("am", "").Trim();

        Hours = int.Parse(timeString.Split(':')[0]);
        Minutes = int.Parse(timeString.Split(':')[1]);
    }

    public TimeSpan ToTimeSpan()
    {
        if (IsAfternoon)
        {
            if (Hours < 12)
            {
                Hours += 12;
            }
        }
        return new TimeSpan(Hours, Minutes, 00);
    }

    public TimeSpan Add(StringTime time2)
    {
        return this.ToTimeSpan().Add(time2.ToTimeSpan());
    }
}
```

Output (the value before the dot are days):

> 1.02:50:00
>   1.03:30:00
>   17:00:00

Answer (score 1):

You can't add those, just like you can't add "14:20PM" and the color red. You can add a time and a timespan (14:20PM + 30 minutes) or two timespans (2 hours+30 minutes). But you cannot add two times.

To make this even clearer, consider what would happen if you could add two times:
14.20 + 00:30 (EST) = 23.20 + 09:30 (UTC)